# Should I separate multiple "ands" in a series with commas?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, nouns, sentence, lists

> I enjoy eating apples and cherries and pears and bananas.

OR

> I enjoy eating apples, and cherries, and pears, and bananas.

I apologize if this question was listed somewhere else, but I can't find a single article discussing it anywhere on the internet. I'm a transcriber. I'm not at liberty to change what a person says, but I need to type it up on paper with best possible grammar. My company prefers the Oxford comma, so the last comma in a series is preferable.

Comment: Was it said with commas or not?

Comment: Oxford comma? 'I enjoy eating apples, and cherries, and pears and bananas.' would be ridiculous, SG. // "I'm not at liberty to change what a person says" means that you will have to faithfully reproduce any errors in syntax, semantics or veracity. But punctuation is not only prescribed in certain areas, but increasingly accepted to be more flexible than the hidebound might wish. You can often (where no confusion will ensue)  choose to indicate pauses in speech rather than just 'correctly offset direct speech' or 'separate items in a list', say. tchrist spells out the fact that you have ...

Comment: the choice here. (He loves to exercise his rights, even trumping the 'Begin every sentence with a capital letter' rule.) Do three pauses or smooth running prose better reflect the way the speaker read out the extract? 3 commas or zero commas are both totally acceptable. (But any other permutation may well code for groupings within the list.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this cannot be the original text, and without knowing what were the original constituents of the sentence users cannot be asked to make judgement calls.

Comment: I don't know if commas are used or intended. I'm listening to a person speaking, ie. audio only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no grammatical need for those commas; the conjunctions are perfectly adequate by themselves to connect the listed items. (This is an example of [polysyndeton](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polysyndeton).)

The Oxford comma is normally used in a series only when commas are used for the series connectors. Therefore, in the absence of any other information, I'd recommend the first sentence that you suggested:

> I enjoy eating apples and cherries and pears and bananas.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Polysyndeton! I didn't know the term for this occurrence. I have seen sentences where multiples "ands" are used and I didn't see commas, but I wasn't sure if it was a journalistic style preference, like using as few commas as possible for readability. My company does not do journal style. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! We usually use commas with more than two items, but conjunctions sometimes work better. ([Lions and tigers and bears, oh my!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HrfbV16-FQ))